# Why is a field norm called a "norm"

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, terminology, galois-theory, normed-spaces

I am studying Galois Theory and we were introduced to the concept of a field norm, which is defined as follows (taken from Wikipedia):

" Let $K$ be a field and $L$ a finite extension of $K$. The field $L$ is then a finite dimensional vector space over $K$.

Multiplication by $\alpha \in L$  given by the map:
$$m_\alpha:L\to L $$
$$ x \mapsto \alpha \cdot x  $$

is a $K$-linear transformation of this vector space into itself.

The **norm** $N_{L / K}(\alpha)$ is defined as the determinant of this linear transformation. "

I understand that the field norm is **not** a "regular" norm in a vector space, and also in Wikipedia it says that "the field norm is very different from the usual distance norm" and an example is given as well. I also saw some more examples distinguishing the field norm from the "usual distance norm".

So, if it is different why call it a norm? Is there any specific case where this field norm actually is related to a norm in a vector space?

I looked around quite a bit for an answer but could not find one, I hope this isn't a duplicate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the case $K=\mathbb R,$ and $L=\mathbb C,$ the norm sends $a+bi\mapsto a^2+b^2.$ While the analytic “norm” on $\mathbb C$ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2},$ that doesn’t work for $K=\mathbb Q, L=\mathbb Q(I).$ If you want $N:Q(i)\mathbb Q.$ I suspect this near-match with the standard norm, plus the fact that the algebraic norm is non-zero for non-zero arguments, and a multiplicative homomorphism, makes it an algebraic relative to the standard norm.

Comment: Note that for a number field $\Bbb{Q}(b)$ then $a\to \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |Tr( a b^n)|$ is a norm in the $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space sense, above the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb{Q}$. For the absolute values there are those coming from the complex embeddings plus the $p$-adic embeddings.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any specific case where this field norm actually is related to a norm in a vector space?

Yes! Consider the finite extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$. Then the norm map $N_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the square of the standard norm, that is
$$N_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}(a + bi) = a^2 + b^2.$$

To see this, consider the ordered basis $(1,i)$ for $\mathbb{C}$. The matrix representation of $m_{a + bi}$ with respect to this ordered basis is
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}$$
which has determinant $a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Usually, the complex norm is defined as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$ But it is close enough.

Comment: Oops! Thank you, I'll edit my answer.